# what is the parametric form for "mystery curve"?

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric, plane-curves

Mystery curve [found here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2015/06/03/mystery-curve/) looks like this :
[image]
Was given by the complex formula : $$e^{it} – \frac{e^{6it}}{2} + i \frac{e^{-14it}}{3} $$

Is the parametric form simpler or the polar form would be simpler (leaving the definition of simpler open in terms of : to be any easier form to remember or what ever open interpretation that would make a nicer formula)

Comment: I'd say polar form. But this in complex coordinates, you can change to cartesian if you like, by taking imaginary part along y's.

Comment: The equation you have is already in polar form. If you wish, you can rewrite it in terms of sine and cosine using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: @A.P. : sorry I am a bit rusty, did polar form come in form of $r=f(\theta$)? If yes then I think it is a bit messier than this (imho)

Comment: Yes, it is the one in terms of radius and angle in the Euclidean plane, and it indeed looks a bit "messier". I simply answered your question "what is the parametric form of [...]?" with "you already have it, more tightly packed".

Comment: You probably won't get a very nice polar representation of this

Comment: @A.P. : I seriously cant see how this is same as parametric form without opening it up using Euler's identity. This formula doesn't explain the periodicity of the curve. If indeed it has a periodicity at all.

Comment: Actually, it does: any map $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ defined by $t \mapsto e^{i\alpha t}$ with $\alpha \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ fixed gives a covering of the complex unit circle (a parametrisation "many $: 1$", if you wish). In particular, those functions are periodic, and a sum of periodic functions is again periodic...

Comment: @A.P. : Thank you, I am going to need some time to comprehend what you are saying.

Comment: You can think of it this way: you have an infinite elastic rope, $\Bbb{R}$, and the function $t \mapsto e^{i\alpha t}$ corresponds to winding it around the unit circle. If $\alpha > 0$ is positive you wind it counterclockwise, while if $\alpha < 0$ you wind it clockwise. Further, if $|\alpha| > 1$ you stretch the rope before winding it, while if $|\alpha| < 1$ you loosen the rope before winding it.

Comment: It appears to be taken verbatim from Frank Farris's [Wheels on Wheels on Wheels](https://scholarcommons.scu.edu/bitstream/handle/11123/722/Wheels%20on%20wheels-Farris.pdf), in the June 1996 edition of Math Mag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a lovely curve, but there is nothing mysterious about it.

By all means leave it in the given parametric form
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto z(t):=e^{it}-{e^{6it}\over2}+ i{e^{-14it}\over3}\qquad(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)\ ,$$
or written in the form $t\mapsto\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$ by separating real and imaginary parts.

What is surprising at first glance is the fivefold symmetry of $\gamma$, given that the number $5$ does  appear nowhere in its definition. About this one can say the following: Any trigonometric polynomial
$$f(t):=\sum_{k=-N}^N c_k\>e^{ikt},\qquad c_k\in{\mathbb C},$$
represents a smooth closed curve in the complex plane. When the right side contains only terms with $k=5n+1$, $\>n\in{\mathbb Z}$,  then the function $f$ has the property 
$$f\left(t+{2\pi\over5}\right)\equiv e^{2\pi i/5}\>f(t)\ ,\tag{1}$$
because
$$e^{i(5n+1)(t+2\pi/5)}\equiv e^{2\pi i/5}\>e^{i(5n+1)t}\ .$$
The functional equation $(1)$ at once gives rise to the fivefold symmetry of $\gamma$ we observe.